# Building Android programs on the command line - basic issue - /tools/android does not exist

Tags: android, shell, adb, android-sdk-tools

I follow the steps given in [this](http://geosoft.no/development/android.html) link in order to build Android programs from the command line.

Following is the initial part of the script I use.

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/tom/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64
DEV_HOME=/home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/

args=("$@")

DEV_HOME=$DEV_HOME${args[0]}

PACKAGE_NAME=${args[1]}

#convert package name org/example(this is how given as input) to org.example
CONVERT_PACKAGE=${PACKAGE_NAME////.}

#Creating New android project
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/android create project --name ${args[0]} --path $DEV_HOME --target android-16 --package $CONVERT_PACKAGE --activity ${args[0]}

#Copying source files into our newly created project
src=/home/tom/Downloads/tom/fwdmusicassimilator/Script_May6

if test -d $DEV_HOME/assets; 
then 
echo "DIR exist"
else
echo "DIR not exists"
mkdir $DEV_HOME/assets
fi
```

When I run the above script in terminal , I get the following output, which points to the fact that `tom/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/tools/android` does not exist. I downloaded the latest android sdk for 64 bit ubuntu from android developer site.

This script used to work perfect before without a single issue in other machines. Now that when I port this to the production environment, I get this problem with the latest sdk from android developer site. I have been after this for long time now and I would really appreciate any help, suggestioons or comments that could help me resolve this and get me out of this time killer.

```
tom@tom-Inspiron-N4050:~/Downloads/tom/fwdmusicassimilator$ ./test_final_6jun.sh mu com/test
./test_final_6jun.sh: line 15: /home/tom/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/tools/android: No such file or directory
DIR not exists
mkdir: cannot create directory `/home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/mu/assets': No such file or directory
./test_final_6jun.sh: line 32: /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/mu/src/com/test/AddPlaylist.java: No such file or directory
./test_final_6jun.sh: line 32: /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/mu/src/com/test/DataBaseHelper.java: No such file or directory
./test_final_6jun.sh: line 32: /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/mu/src/com/test/DownloadAudioFile.java: No such file or directory
./test_final_6jun.sh: line 32: /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/mu/src/com/test/MainPerspectivesListActivity.java: No such file or directory
./test_final_6jun.sh: line 32: /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/mu/src/com/test/MusicListActivity.java: No such file or directory
./test_final_6jun.sh: line 32: /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/mu/src/com/test/MusicPlayerActivity.java: No such file or directory
./test_final_6jun.sh: line 32: /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/mu/src/com/test/PlaylistSongsSelectActivity.java: No such file or directory
```

**EDIT**

Based on what Commonsware pointed out below, as comment to my question, I made the required correction, and here is the terminal log with the error that begins with `/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/platform-tools/aapt: No such file or directory`

```
tom@tom-Inspiron-N4050:~$ cd /home/tom/Downloads/tom/fwdmusicassimilator
tom@tom-Inspiron-N4050:~/Downloads/tom/fwdmusicassimilator$ ./test_final_6jun.sh music88 com/abc
Created project directory: /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88
Created directory /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/src/com/abc
Added file /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/src/com/abc/music88.java
Created directory /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/res
Created directory /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/bin
Created directory /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/libs
Created directory /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/res/values
Added file /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/res/values/strings.xml
Created directory /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/res/layout
Added file /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/res/layout/main.xml
Created directory /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/res/drawable-xhdpi
Created directory /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/res/drawable-hdpi
Created directory /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/res/drawable-mdpi
Created directory /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/res/drawable-ldpi
Added file /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/AndroidManifest.xml
Added file /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/build.xml
Added file /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/proguard-project.txt
DIR not exists
no files to copy
no files to copy
no files to copy
no files to copy
Does not exist
Generating 1,024 bit RSA key pair and self-signed certificate (SHA1withRSA) with a validity of 10,000 days
    for: CN=company name, OU=organisational unit, O=organisation, L=location, ST=state, C=country code
[Storing /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/AndroidTest.keystore]
./test_final_6jun.sh: line 176: /home/tom/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/platform-tools/aapt: No such file or directory
DIR not exists
[parsing started RegularFileObject[/home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/src/com/abc/AddPlaylist.java]]
[parsing completed 15ms]
[parsing started RegularFileObject[/home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/src/com/abc/DataBaseHelper.java]]
[parsing completed 16ms]
[parsing started RegularFileObject[/home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/src/com/abc/DownloadAudioFile.java]]
[parsing completed 2ms]
[parsing started RegularFileObject[/home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/src/com/abc/MainPerspectivesListActivity.java]]
[parsing completed 2ms]
[parsing started RegularFileObject[/home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/src/com/abc/music88.java]]
[parsing completed 3ms]
[parsing started RegularFileObject[/home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/src/com/abc/MusicListActivity.java]]
[parsing completed 9ms]
[parsing started RegularFileObject[/home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/src/com/abc/MusicPlayerActivity.java]]
[parsing completed 10ms]
[parsing started RegularFileObject[/home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/src/com/abc/PlaylistSongsSelectActivity.java]]
[parsing completed 5ms]
[parsing started RegularFileObject[/home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/src/com/abc/SongPlayService.java]]
[parsing completed 4ms]
[parsing started RegularFileObject[/home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/src/com/abc/SongsActivity.java]]
[parsing completed 0ms]
[parsing started RegularFileObject[/home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/src/com/abc/SpecificPerspectiveListActivity.java]]
[parsing completed 6ms]
[parsing started RegularFileObject[/home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/src/com/abc/Utilities.java]]
[parsing completed 1ms]
[search path for source files: /home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/src]
[search path for class files: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/netx.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/plugin.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rhino.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/modules/jdk.boot.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/classes,/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/pulse-java.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/java-atk-wrapper.jar,/home/tom/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/platforms/android-16/android.jar,/home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/obj]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/lib/ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/IOException.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/lib/ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/util/ArrayList.class)]]
/home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/src/com/abc/AddPlaylist.java:6: package android.app does not exist
import android.app.ActionBar;
              ^
/home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/src/com/abc/AddPlaylist.java:7: package android.app does not exist
import android.app.Activity;
              ^
/home/tom/Downloads/tom/generated_assimilators/music88/src/com/abc/AddPlaylist.java:8: package android.content does not exist
import android.content.Intent;
                  ^
```

Comment: I think it would now be `.../sdk/tools/android`, but that's going from memory.

Comment: infact, I see `.../sdk/tools/android` file, it is a script file. I presume, that is the file, the above script is referring to, but then I do not understand, why it says does not exist.

Comment: Your script isn't looking for `/home/tom/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/sdk/tools/android`. Your script is looking in `/home/tom/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/tools/android`.

Answer (score 2):

The latest Android SDT moved some tools to the `build-tools` folder and others to the `platform-tools` folders: you might want to try either copying the files from there to a folder you're expecting, or point to the right place.